# minFileSizeForComp is not working for dynamic compression in IIS10

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-10

I am trying to change the minFileSizeForComp from the default of 2700 bytes to 860 bytes. But it is not working for dynamic compression gzip/deflate.

I am able to compress API response <2700 bytes as well. IIS httpcompression "minFileSizeForComp" property does not seems to be working for dynamic compression.

Is there any way to make it work at server/site level for IIS10 . Appreciate the help!

Need to set the minimum response size for dynamic compression as 860 bytes.
IIS httpcompression "minFileSizeForComp" property does not seems to be working for dynamic compression.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP client must initiate communication for compressed content by sending the appropriate HTTP Accept-encoding header. If a client is not capable of HTTP compression, it will not pass that header and IIS will always return uncompressed content, so please check how good your Accept-Encoding is working on the site.

To check Accept-Encoding in action go to Inspect Element -> Network check the request header for Accept-Encoding

Comment: thank you for your response. I am sending "Accept-Encoding" request header as gzip/deflate. It is working fine for both compressions when configured at server (applicationHost.config) level. The problem is, I am not able to set the minimum response size for dynamic compression for APIs. All API response regardless of the size are getting compressed. "minFileSizeForComp" does not seems to be working for dynamic compression.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1513903/minfilesizeforcomp-is-not-working-for-dynamic-comp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1513903/minfilesizeforcomp-is-not-working-for-dynamic-comp).